# Android Package Name Dex Issue

Tags: android, gradle, dex

I'm to trying create an application with package name "**com.cvs.myapp**". App builds perfectly but crashes in device at runtime.

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.cvs.myapp/com.cvs.myapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.cvs.myapp.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.cvs.myapp-DG6fxWRjVXjsKQV_vwJwAw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.cvs.myapp-DG6fxWRjVXjsKQV_vwJwAw==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2843)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.cvs.myapp.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.cvs.myapp-DG6fxWRjVXjsKQV_vwJwAw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.cvs.myapp-DG6fxWRjVXjsKQV_vwJwAw==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:69)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:41)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1215)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2831)
```

It's just a new project with no other additions containing only a MainActivity class. Same new project will work if i rename the package to "com.demo.myapp".

Using Analyse APK, I can see that the classes.dex file doesn't contain the MainActivity. Is the name "cvs" causing the issue as it will work perfectly with any other name instead of it?

gradle-wrapper.properties

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip`

build.gradle(project)

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'`

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.cvs.myapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name="com.cvs.myapp.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22027219/proguard-seeming-to-remove-an-entire-packages-that-are-included-in-the-path

Comment: I don't believe it's a proguard issue as the same project will run perfectly if I rename the package name. It has got something to do with current the name I think. Also the same project will run on device if I change the gradle versions to
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
.It was working fine till I updated the versions to the latest.

Comment: did you add `multiDexEnabled true`?

Comment: Yes, I had added. Didn't work. Even if i don't add add this and refactor the package name, it will run without any crash in device.

Comment: Looks like name "cvs" was being excluded according to link https://github.com/gradle/gradle/search?q=cvs&unscoped_q=cvs. Followed solution provided in link https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/11017.

Added :
org.apache.tools.ant.DirectoryScanner.removeDefaultExclude("**/CVS")
org.apache.tools.ant.DirectoryScanner.removeDefaultExclude("**/CVS/**") to settings.gradle

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned this is happening when you are using the latest Gradle that is currently 3.6.3, It has a new packaging tool [ZipFlinger](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin), which might be causing the issue, try below code to disable it

```
android.useNewApkCreator=false
```

Moreover I got some relevant links, please have a look.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150198184

[After upgrading to android 3.6.1 apk cant be installed on devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60549869/after-upgrading-to-android-3-6-1-apk-cant-be-installed-on-devices)

[Android App runtime crash after update gradle plugin 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60423895/android-app-runtime-crash-after-update-gradle-plugin-3-6)

[MultiDex problem with Android Studio 3.6 when implementing it the right way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60411392/multidex-problem-with-android-studio-3-6-when-implementing-it-the-right-way)

Comment: I had already tried this but the issue still persists. There is something else which is happening, I'm not sure. As i said, even without using the above code, my project will run on device with the latest gradle versions if I simply refactor the package name from "com.cvs.myapp" to "com.demo.myapp" or "com.sample.myapp". It's the word "cvs" which is causing the issue apparently.